# Assign variable from database

Tags: python, mysql, totp

I'm trying to create a python smart lock thing using rfid and the password instead of regular "1234", I'm using Time OTP with [PyOTP Libray](https://github.com/pyauth/pyotp).

At the moment I'm stuck with how to assign the `secret` variable value at the if function using data from `secret` from table users.

How do I do assign the  `secret` value from users table to the variable `secret`

**IF FUNCTION**

```
print("Place card near scanner")
id, text = reader.read()
cursor.execute("Select id From users Where rfid_uid="+str(id))
result = cursor.fetchone()

if cursor.rowcount > = 1:
   print("Welcome\nType the code from your authenticator app")
   secret = ('''The data from "secret" in users table''')
```

**users Table**

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
| id | rfid_uid     | name        | secret           | created             |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 939940479059 | Blue Dongle | LONGSTRINGOFCODE | 2020-12-10 09:07:34 |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the select statement you should be able to select the `secret` in addition to the `id`.

```py
print("Place card near scanner")
id, text = reader.read()
cursor.execute("SELECT id, secret FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
result = cursor.fetchone()

if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
    print("Welcome\nType the code from your authenticator app")
    secret = result[1]
```

Comment: It said `No result set to fetch from` from the `rows = cursor.fetchall()`
But when I edited `result = cursor.fetchone()` to `fetchall()` and change the line after the `print` to only `secret = result[1]` it respond with `index out of range`,and if its `secret = result[0]` it simply respond with print `id` and `secret`. Any idea why it happend?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer. Once fetchone() is called, fetchall() can't grab the result that was already fetched.